# PDOを使った異なるデータベースのテーブル結合方法

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

PDOクラスを利用した同一サーバー内にある異なるデータベースのテーブル結合の方法が分からず、、、お知恵を授けていただけますと嬉しいです。
開発言語はPHP、データベースはMYSQLです。

やりたきことは以下2つのテーブルのidをキーとして内部結合させ、member_nameとgroup_nameカラムを抽出したいです。

データベース名 / テーブル名
DB1 / table1
DB2 / table2

ここ↓↓の記述方法が間違っているとは思うのですが、正しい記述が分かりません。
`$stmt=$dbh1-> prepare($sql);`

プログラミング初心者のため、不足している情報などありましたら申し訳ございません。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```php
$dsn1 = 'mysql:dbname=DB1;host=localhost;charset=utf8';
$user1 = 'root';
$password1 = '******';

$dsn2 = 'mysql:dbname=DB2;host=localhost;charset=utf8';
$user2 = 'root';
$password2 = '******';

try{
  $dbh1 = new PDO($dsn1, $user1, $password1);
  $dbh1 -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $dbh1 -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);

  $dbh2 = new PDO($dsn2, $user2, $password2);
  $dbh2 -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $dbh2 -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);

  $sql=
    "SELECT tb1.member_name,tb2.group_name
     FROM DB1.table1 tb1
     INNER JOIN DB2.table2 tb2 ON tb1.id = tb2.id";
  $stmt=$dbh1-> prepare($sql);
  $stmt-> execute();

}catch(PDOException $Exception){
    print "エラー:".$Exception->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: そのスクリプトを実行するとどうなるのか(エラーになるのか期待する結果が得られないのか)を質問を編集して追記してください

Comment: `$sql=...` のステートメントには末尾に `;` がありませんが、記載ミスですか？

Comment: @heliac2001 `;`は必要なんでしょうか。ライブラリ経由の場合、(複文を使わない限り)`;`を必要とした場面に出会った記憶がありません。PDOでも`;`が無くても動くようですが。

Comment: @suzukis いえ、PHP コードのステートメントに `;` がないという事です。

Answer (score 1):

まずデータベースへの接続はひとつで構いません。接続ユーザには、両方のデータベースに対する権限を与えておきます。

その上で、以下のようなSQL文でいけると思います。

```
SELECT tb1.member_name, tb2.group_name
FROM DB1.table1 AS tb1, DB2.table2 AS tb2
INNER JOIN tb2 ON tb1.id = tb2.id
```